# Connecting to MetaMask using Web3.js: Web3.givenProvider vs window.ethereum

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps, web3-providers, brave-browser

I am currently attempting to programmatically connect to MetaMask using Web3.js. I am following the Getting Started guide (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v3.0.0-rc.5/getting-started.html), and the tutorial mentions the following:

> Most Ethereum-supported browsers like MetaMask have an EIP-1193
> compliant provider available at `window.ethereum`. For Web3.js, check
> `Web3.givenProvider`.

As I am using Web3.js, I am using `Web3.givenProvider` instead of `window.ethereum`. Unfortunately, I am currently experiencing the issue that `Web3.givenProvider` is `null` for me, even though I have MetaMask installed as a browser extension, and I am logged into my Ethereum account on the MainNet.

From other tutorials, I am aware of the `window.ethereum` object, which I checked out of curiosity, and indeed, it is present. The first uncertainty I have is: What is the difference between `window.ethereum` and `Web3.givenProvider`, and why is one present while the other is not? According to the previously quoted Web3.js documentation, I must use `Web3.givenProvider`, correct?

[image]

My current setup is as follows: A React app with **Web3.js version 4.2.0** and TypeScript. I am testing this in the Vite development server and using the Brave browser.

Any insights into the differences between `window.ethereum` and `Web3.givenProvider` and why `Web3.givenProvider` might be `null` in my case would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `Web3.givenProvider` is no longer available in web3.js v**4**.x versions and `window.ethereum` should be used instead (see https://docs.web3js.org/guides/web3_providers_guide/#injected-providers). Since I followed web3.js v**3**.x documentation but am using web3.js v**4**, it might explain why `Web3.givenProvider` is `null` for me. But I'm wondering why the `Web3.givenProvider` variable isn't retained for backwards compatibility reasons?!
Anyway, `new Web3(window.ethereum);` solves my current problem.

Answer (score 0):

right, as you said, `new Web3(window.ethereum)` is the answer for it.
Also, I would encourage you to deep dive into 4.x, the 1.x will be deprecated in a few months, ChainSafe team has been rewriting the whole library in TypeScript since 2020 and it was released a few months ago.